# Create new database for release?

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design, architecture

We have a database that holds all kinds of record for all our software products. Some of the records are for a specific software and some records are shared by different software.
Different team will lock, edit and update the database.
When we release different software, we just grab this single big database and release it with the software.

Here is the problem:

- The database might grow bigger and it contains unnecessary information for one software since it holds all the records for all the software products.
- It seems very easy for people to screw up: the database you're editing might not be the latest one; the change might break other software, etc...

I'm wondering what's the usual solution for this kind of problem, here are the solutions I can think of:

1. Keep the mother database and generate child databases for different software.
   Different team can use a web interface to add records to the mother database and when releasing, run a task that basically copies the necessary tables from the mother database and creates a new database for the release.
2. Don't use the mother database. Different software uses different database. But how to deal with the shared records?

Comment: Is this database read only for your customers, or do they write to the database by using your software?

Comment: Database is readonly for customers.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with your first approach.  That's what I thought of before I read your answers.  The advantage of having a "mother" database is that you can make all software products conform to the same schema. They all share the same template, if you will.

Then when you are ready for a release, like you said, you run a process and a compact version of the database is generated and ready to ship.

Option 2 is a bad idea because of schema updates. It's very similar in concept to forking a codebase. If you fork your codebase 10 times, then when a bug fix comes in you have to go to 10 places to fix it and release it.

Also consider that having one mother database allows you to easily make queries across all of them. "How many releases do we have? How many products do we have? What was the last product we released?"

If you split the databases, that kind of query is much harder to write.